# Dust stellar cloud self-gravitationnal field expression

Tags: newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics

I see no topic on this subject:

Does a self attracting gravitational field exist for a stellar cloud of mixed heavy rocks and dusts acting on itself?

The gravitational potential $V(\mathbf{r})$ created by a gas of dust and particles of finite density $ \mu(\mathbf{r})$ is given by Poisson's equation:

$$ \Delta  V(\mathbf{r}) = - G \mu(\mathbf{r}) $$

So using Green function we have in free-space:

$$ V = - \frac{G}{4 \pi} \iiint \frac{\mu(\mathbf{r'})}{ \Vert \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}  \Vert } d V'$$

Then the corresponding gravitational field $\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r})$ is:

$$ \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r}) = - \mathbf{\nabla} V = - \frac{G}{4 \pi} \iiint \frac{\mu(\mathbf{r'})}{ \Vert \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}  \Vert^3 } ( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'} )  d V' $$

So now, tell me if I'm wrong, the force per unit volume of the cloud acting on itself (that means: a spatial region of mass which are attracting an other spatial region of mass) should be the following:

$$ \mathbf{f} = \mu(\mathbf{r}) \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r}) = - \mu(\mathbf{r}) \frac{G}{4 \pi} \iiint \frac{\mu(\mathbf{r'})}{ \Vert \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}  \Vert^3 } ( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'} )  d V' $$

This seems right no?

Comment: Sorry guys in fact it is true and I found it in an astrodynamics textbook, maybe should I supress this topic for moderators ?